# Firefox not getting value when using: document.getElementById().value

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the `Click Here!!!` I get the two `alert()` messages but instead of the values `BBB` and `ZZZ` that I expect, I get `undefined` and `undefined`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? **I'm running Firefox 8.0, works in IE 8**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<div id="1_0">
    <div id='1_1'  style="background-color: yellow;">
        <input="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
        <input="hidden" id="1_b" value="BBB"/>
        some text, and some more
        <div>
            <div style="background-color: silver;" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('1_b').value);alert(document.getElementById('1_z').value);">
                Click Here!!!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<input="hidden" id="1_z" value="ZZZ"/>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

problem is with the input=hidden. It should be `<input type="hidden">`

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<div id="1_0">
    <div id='1_1'  style="background-color: yellow;">
        <input type="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="1_b" value="BBB"/>
        some text, and some more
        <div>
            <div style="background-color: silver;" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('1_b').value);alert(document.getElementById('1_z').value);">
                Click Here!!!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<input type="hidden" id="1_z" value="ZZZ"/>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an error in your HTML markup on these lines:

```
<input="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
<input="hidden" id="1_b" value="BBB"/>
```

These need to be:

```
<input type="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
<input type="hidden" id="1_b" value="BBB"/>
```

Notice the `type` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

- Your element definition should be:

  ```
  <input type="hidden" .../>
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  <input="hidden" .../>
  ```
- Try [starting your `id` with an alpha character](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-name) (probably isn't the problem, but they should anyway).

Answer (score 1):

First off, your inputs should be `<input type="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="1_b" value="BBB"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input="hidden"
```

is wrong, you need:

```
<input type="hidden"
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2PSB/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a wring markup. instead of

```
<input="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
```

it should be

```
<input type="hidden" id="1_a" value="AAA"/>
```